# How should I instantiate a property (i.e. currentUser) specifically AFTER the user has logged in?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsf, authentication

Our project is Spring + Spring Security + Maven + Hibernate + JSF + Icefaces

We need to define values for currentUser, but it cannot be defined until after the user has logged in.

```
public static UserDetails currentUserDetails(){
    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
    if (authentication != null) {
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        return (UserDetails) (principal instanceof UserDetails ? principal : null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

If we try to include definition in server startup, a nullpointerException is thrown(as expected).

Our current method is to lazily define it in the getter method. So whenever the JSF calls it, an HQL is ran but this is very expensive.

Could someone give advice on how to run currentUserDetails method only once AFTER the user has already logged in?

Comment: Save it in the session once the login process completes?

Comment: If HQL is run on every getter method invocation, then it's definitely not lazy. You've a design problem in your lazy loading.

Comment: Each of the different getter methods is ran once lazily. I would like to define the userDetails once beforehand so that each getter method is now calling an already defined value.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `<form-login>` tag in your security.xml file - you can define success login callback, like

```
<form-login 
authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.test.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

and bean impl

```
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
   // use authentication object to fetch the user object and update its timestamp
   }
}
```

I hope it will be helpful. Good luck.